# JavaScript data not loading after async and await

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to fetch data from an API and load that data onto a website using React. Currently, I am calling the fetch function using async and await. I printed out the results of the fetch call and all seems to be working properly. What I don't understand is why my studentsJSON array is still empty even though there is an array in data.students.

```
  const [studentsJSON, setStudentsJSON] = useState([])
  const [students, setStudents] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      const response = await fetch(URL)
      const data = await response.json()
      console.log(`data.students: ${data.students}`)
      setStudentsJSON(data.students)
      console.log(`studentsJSON: ${studentsJSON}`)
      for (let student of studentsJSON) {
        setStudents(students => [...students, new Student(student)])
      }
      console.log(`students: ${students}`)
    }

    fetchData()
  }, [])
```

Output:

```
data.students: [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
App.js:36 studentsJSON: 
App.js:40 students:
```

Comment: State is constant within a particular render of a component; for component to see the updated state, it has to re-render. As a result, logging the state right after calling the state updater function will log the old state. You can use `useEffect` hook to log the updated state: `useEffect(() => { console.log(studentsJSON); }, [studentsJSON]);`

Comment: Please make another function outside of useEffect pass your state into that function and inside the function place yours for a loop.

or make a callback of setStudentsJSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `await response.json()` already turns your JSON into a JS data structure so the `studentsJSON` and `setStudentsJSON` state really makes no sense.
2. You might want to reconsider how you update your state. [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the data to create a new array, create a new state array, and then update your student state in one move.

   ```
   const newStudents = data.students.map(student => new Student(student));
   const newState = [...students, newStudents].flat();
   setStudents(newState);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can't see your `studentsJSON` because setState (setStudentsJSON) is an asynchronous operation, and by the time it runs the command `console.log` the state value `studentsJSON` is still an empty array.

Instead of logging the result immediately after setState, you can put it inside another useEffect hook:

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(studentsJSON);
}, [studentsJSON]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using promises. This solves the problem of setting state empty.

```
 const response = await fetch(URL).then((res)=>setStudentsJSON( res.json()))
```